# Disproving $ L^2(X, U(\mathbb{C},n)) = U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n))$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

Here $X$ is some measurable space  and  $U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n))$ denotes the Banach space of unitary automorphisms of the Hilbert space $L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n)$.

Let $U(\mathbb{C},n)$ denote the unitary matrices $n\times n$, we can consider the space of $L^2$ functions  $\phi: X\to U(\mathbb{C},n)$, denoted as $L^2(X, U(\mathbb{C},n))$.
An element $\phi$ in the latter space defines an element in $U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n))$ that sends $f\in L^2(X, \mathbb{C}^n)$ to $\phi\cdot f $ such that

$\phi \cdot f(x) = \phi(x) (f(x))$.

Since $\phi(x)$ is unitary, it preserves the norms hence $\phi\cdot f\in L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n)$ (this is why I am taking the unitary group and not $GL$) and the operator norm is $1$.
Therefore we have an inclusion

$L^2(X, U(\mathbb{C},n))\to U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n)) $

> Is this map an isomorphism?
> Can you provide an example of an element of $U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n))$ which is not in the image of the above map?

I believe the answer to the first question is negative. The LHS is an Hilbert space while the RHS is a Banach (but I cannot disprove that it can't be given an Hilbert structure, e.g. is it reflexive? I don't know).

Also, I thought that $U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n))$ is contractible (at least if $\dim L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n) = \infty$)  by Kuipers' theorem, therefore another possible way of disproving it would be show that $L^2(X, U(\mathbb{C},n))$ has more connected components.

Comment: What you're calling $L^2(X,U)$ is not a vector space. Unitary matrices are not closed under addition or scalar multiplication. So what isomorphism are you looking for?

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks, good point. Neither $U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n)$ is. They are both Banach Lie groups I think. Anyway I am mostly interested in isomorphism as topological spaces or groups. I will change the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here. First, you need a measure to define $L^2(X,U(n))$, not just a measurable space. Moreover, $L^2(X,U(n))$ is not a Hilbert space or even a vector space - neither sums nor scalar multiples of unitaries are unitary in general. In fact, if the underlying measure is infinite, then $L^2(X,U(n))=\emptyset$. For similar reasons, $U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n))$ is not a vector space.

Even if the underlying measure is finie, the map from the question is almost never surjective. To see this, note that a bounded linear operator of the form
$$
Tf(x)=\psi(x)f(x)
$$
with $\psi(x)\in\mathbb{C}$ for a.e. $x$ commutes with all elements of the image of $L^2(X,U(n))$, but the only operators commuting with all elements of $U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n))$ are scalar multiples of the identity. So the map cannot be surjective if $\dim L^2(X)\geq 2$.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to correct  the question but you answered my curiosity in the end. 
Do you know if $U(L^2(X,\mathbb{C}^n)$ is a Banach manifold? Also, can we say something about the connected components of $L^2(X,U(n))$? So to disprove that the inclusion is not an homotopy equivalence.